# How can i run ajax on php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to use javascript code on my codeIgniter project. But I didn't execute it. I tried too many ways for solve it: I called the external js code, it didn't work. I put in my view page it dind't work as well. I think the problem is simple but I can't see it. What do you think about this problem?

**view.php**

```
<html>
<?php include("/external/css/style.css"); ?>
<head>
<title>New Customer</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function makeAjaxCall(){
    $.ajax({
        alert("I'm here"); // I cant see that
        type: "post",
        url: "http://localhost/codeigniter_2/index.php/homepage/verifyUser",
        cache: false,               
        data: $('#addCust').serialize(),
        success: function(json){                        
        try{        
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
            alert( obj['STATUS']);


        }catch(e) {     
            alert('Exception while request..');
        }       
        },
        error: function(){                      
            alert('Error while request..');
        }
 });
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Customer Add</h1><a href="http://localhost/codeigniter_2/index.php">list</a>
    <form name="addCust" method="post" action="insert">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Customer Name:</th>
<td><input type="text" id="custom" name="customerName"/></td>
<tr>
<th>Customer Phone:</th>
<td><input type="text" name="phone"/></td>
<tr>
<th>Address:</th>
<td><input type="text" name="address"/></td>
.
.
.
<tr>
<td><input type="button" onclick="javascript:makeAjaxCall();" value="Submit"></td>
<td><input type="reset"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

**conroller.php**

```
public function verifyUser()
    {
        $userName =  $_POST['customerID'];
        $phone =  $_POST['phone'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        if($userName=='' && $phone=11){

            $status = array("STATUS"=>"true");  
        }
        echo json_encode ($status) ;    
    }
```

What's wrong??

Comment: Did you try with a simple `return json_encode()` in your controller?

Comment: Drop out your `alert(I'm Here)` in your ajax call. It is not it's right place

Answer (score 5):

You need to put your code in a document ready handler -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
    function makeAjaxCall....
    // EDIT: adding the click handler
    $('#formSubmit').click(function()....
});
```

Also, instead of doing this -

```
<input onclick="javascript:makeAjaxCall();" value="Submit">
```

I would give the input an id -

```
<input name="submit" id="formSubmit" value="Submit">
```

And add a click handler to the JavaScript -

```
$('#formSumbit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // keeps the button from acting normally
    makeAjaxCall(); // calls the function
});
```

One more thing - use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` in your code. Alerts are not a good method of troubleshooting because they cause the code to halt until acknowledgement and using them during an AJAX call is especially bad.

Comment: document ready is not required , because function is called on button click

Comment: It may not be required @rajeshkakawat, but it will insure that the function is available and that the jQuery is properly bound when the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:makeAjaxCall();" value="Submit">
```

to

```
<input type="button" onclick="makeAjaxCall();" value="Submit">
```

**EDITED**

```
$userName =  $_POST['customerID'];// check this
$phone =  $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
if($userName=='' && $phone=11){

    $status = array("STATUS"=>"true");
}
echo json_encode ($status) ;
```

also add `id` to form

```
<form name="addCust" id="addCust" method="post" action="insert">
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when I tried to copy it to here. In my project this code is as you said. But it doesn't work ass well

Comment: remove alert from ajax, it breaking ajax function

Answer (score 0):

Hello Here you can check the below link and it will useful for you

```
    http://www.ccode4u.com/how-jquery-ajax-works-in-codeigniter.html﻿
```

Thank you :)