# Execute function on button click Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter.
I want to create a button in a view that when clicked will execute a function from a controller.

i am using right now this code in the view:

```
<button id="checkin" onclick="location.href='
<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/daily_attendance/check_in'">Check in</button>
```

this code will not only execute the function `check_in`, but will also get me to that page.
i can easily use `redirect()` in the controller of the function and get back to wherever i want.

The problem is that i have a jquery which hide this button on click and show another button.
but when i execute the function then redirect, the page refresh and the button is not shown.

my question is that, is there a better way to execute functions without going to another page in codeigniter?

is there a way to pass the function to the button or should i make the button in the controller which is not advisable since it's not for UI components and because i will need to create many views to manage the UI properly since the button will be in the middle of the page?

Comment: You need to use AJAX. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824603/how-can-i-run-ajax-on-php-codeigniter

Comment: thanks for your fast replay, but what about the best way to call functions without moving or refreshing the page?
Is this the best way to call functions?

Comment: i am using ajax
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("button#checkout").hide();
    
    $("button#checkin").click(function(){
        $("button#checkin").hide();
        $("button#checkout").show();
        
    });
    $("button#checkout").click(function(){
         $("button#checkin").show();
        $("button#checkout").hide();
    });
});
</script>

Comment: add that information to your original post

Comment: the problem is that 
$(document).ready will be executed again when i press the button

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can call function of a controller on button click.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>daily_attendance/check_in/<?php echo $stdrow->student_id;  ?>"  class="btn red" style="height: 20px; border-radius:4px;">Check in</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href = "<?= base_url('index.php/daily_attendance/check_in')">
```

Comment: i wonder why someone is down-casting the question and the answers?

Comment: this answer probably got downvoted, because it's only one lone of code without explanation. There should be more explanation in it at least.

Comment: It's a direct, straight forward answer to the question. No explanation needed.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is the same thing as changing the location of the url 
I think that you can't call functions of the controller in the view without getting redirected to the controller .
this is the whole point of MVC pattern 

so, what i need to do is to pass the data only to the view and put the ajax in the controller 
i am going to try that then update u with the result